# Retornar um array da query php

Tags: php

Bom dia, estou começando com php e estou com a seguinte duvida
Estou populando um gráfico que é das solicitações MENSAIS, em js

A maneira para poupar ele é a seguinte:

```
                       ...
                       pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                       pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                       data: [12,11,10,9,8,7,8,8,5,5,3,4] //AQUI POPULA
               },
```

Tenho a seguinte consulta no banco:

```
select COUNT(SolID) total from Solicitacao where 
UsuIDGrupoRespConclusao = 2655
AND DATEPART(yyyy, SolData) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, 0, getdate()))
group by MONTH(soldata)
```

Essa consulta me consulta TODAS as solicitações ANUAIS, irá me retornar 11 linhas, a primeira para o mês de janeiro, segunda fevereiro e assim sucessivamente.

Como faço pro meu PHP consultar no banco e armazenar esse retorno (apenas uma consulta) dentro de 12 variaveis, e assim eu preencher este gráfico?

Comment: Coloca o código em texto que é mais facil de visualizar

Comment: Tem como vc postar o código? Vi que tem uma imagem mas nem todos conseguem ver. Via código fica mais facil analisar.

Comment: Pronto, troquei

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito facil de se fazer é transformar a array de 11 linhas em uma string com os dados separados por virgula, ai você só coloca a string no data do json, em php se faz assim:

```
$suaArray = array('12','11','10','9','8','7','8','8','5','5','3','4');
$suaString = implode(",", $suaArray);
```